# Vaadin compile google maps addon with maven

Tags: eclipse, google-maps, maven, gwt, vaadin

Im trying to integrate google maps in an application, however compiling googlemaps addon with maven is proving to be a real pain for me. I followed many posts regarding this issue but nothing seems to work. I configured the pom.xml as follows:

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Furthermore i created the my_project_nameWidgetSet.gwt.xml and after i run vaadin:compile it generates the necessary lines as follows:

```
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet" />
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.Widgetset" />
</module>
```

However it fails to generate the client side javascript files and the same exception occurs over and over:

```
 Loading inherited module 'com.sensormatic.gpstracking.widgetset.GpsTrackingWidgetset'
[INFO]    Loading inherited module 'com.vaadin.tapio.googlemaps.Widgetset'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Line 3: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
[INFO] java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:324)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:502)
[INFO]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:374)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:502)
[INFO]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:294)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:347)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$200(ReflectiveParser.java:68)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:418)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:374)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:288)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:231)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:160)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:135)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:130)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:100)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:107)
[INFO]       [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
[INFO] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is this exception about and how can i eventually resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating your google web toolkit to see if that takes care of the exception.